# React: sending component as html + css to server?

Tags: reactjs, django, pdf, serialization, components

I want to send react component with styles, as it looks on dev server, to another server (django in my case), and there create a PDF with exact look. So I want to pass identical component (as html with styles?) via POST to server. I've found `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` and it works, but it cant provide styles. Any solutions? Thanks.